# RadComboBox doesn't drop downing in ie 10

Tags: c#, telerik

My RadComboBox doesn't drop downing in ie 10.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox skin="WebBlue" Width="271px" MarkFirstMatch="True" ID="RadComboBoxClientType" AutoPostBack="true"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ClientType_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" >
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Comment: What version of Telerik do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a meta tag and emulate ie9 by setting 
`http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9"`

For more information please check
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/combobox/radcombobox-not-opening-in-ie10.aspx